# Undefined function or variable "Vk" when using sysic to create an interconnected system

Tags: matlab, control-theory

I am attempting to use sysic to create an interconnected system from a number of state space models. However; I keep recieving the same error:

> ```
> Undefined function or variable "Vk".
>
> Error in sysic (line 212)
>    [ard,arl,er] = LOCALpass1(Vk);
>
> Error in addOutputWeights (line 62)
>     sysic
> ```

The code used that generates this error is as follows:

```
systemnames = 'plantModel WControl WError';  
inputvar = '[r(4);  u(4)]'; 
outputvar = '[WControl; WError;r- plantModel]'; 

input_to_WError = '[r-plantModel]';
input_to_WControl = '[u]';
sysoutname = 'instramentedPlant';
cleanupsysic= 'yes';
sysic
```

Answer (score 1):

This error was caused because `input_to_plantModel` was not present in the workspace. For every system that is refered to in `systemnames` there must be a corresponding `input_to_X`.

The following code runs correctly

```
systemnames='plantModel wControl wError';
inputvar ='[r(4);  u(4)]';
outputvar ='[wControl;wError;r- plantModel]';
input_to_plantModel ='[u]';
input_to_wError ='[r-plantModel]';
input_to_wControl ='[u]';
sysoutname ='instramentedPlant';
cleanupsysic = 'yes';
```